# Selenium C# Pop-up handling

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to fetch text from pop up window using Selenium and C#.

[image]

A similar example can be found at-. https://demoqa.com/browser-windows - click on New window Message button. I need get message from the opened window.
(**Note**: I am not using Robot framework)
I tried with Alert class, Javascript and WindowHandles but nothing worked.

WindowHandles Try:

```
foreach (var windowHandle in Webdriver.Driver.WindowHandles)
                {
                    if (!windowHandle.Equals(Webdriver.Driver.CurrentWindowHandle))
                    {
                        Webdriver.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Javascript try:

```
String javaScript = "var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" +
                "evObj.initMouseEvent(\"mouseover\",true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);" +
                "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);";


IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
executor.ExecuteScript(javaScript, webElement);
```

Comment: Any error message you got in both cases ??

Comment: It gives me element not visible exception, but in general the issue is accessing the pop up message window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below snippet to check if you are switching to the correct window to troubleshoot this.

```
var availableWindows = new List<string>(driver.WindowHandles);
foreach (string w in availableWindows)
{
    driver.SwitchTo().Window(w);
    if (driver.Title == "<NEW WINDOW TITLE HERE>")
    {
       Console.WriteLine("SWITCHED TO CORRECT WINDOW!!!");
       Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NOT THE CORRECT WINDOW !!"); 
        Console.WriteLine(driver.Title);   
    }
}
```

Comment: It's untitled window. It throws error on ant "driver." operation